# How can I change the value of a variable in the user interface in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have to find a way to connect a variable to a text insertion field to make it possible to change the value of the variable by rewriting it from the user interface.

Comment: There are many online tutorials to help you with this, please do some research before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```
var stringTest = String()
@IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!

@IBAction func changeText(_ sender: UITextField) {
    stringTest = sender.text!
    labelText.text = stringTest
}
```

And link the action "changeText" with your textField using this:
[image]

so, when you change the text for your textField, change the variable, and in this example, you can see the variable in screen:

[image]

hope this code helps you